# OpenGL c++, какая последовательность работы с текстурой?

Tags: c++, opengl

Я изучаю библиотеку OpenGL.
У меня есть готовый массив пикселей картинки.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю что бы хотя просто вывести текстуру нужны две функции?
   glCreateTextures // создать текстуру, где я в параметрах указываю массив пикселей.
   glBindTexture // и привязать ее
   Правильно же я понял?
2. Если так то эти функции нужно закинуть прямо в цикл? Или вне тела цикла?

Comment: OpenGL какой, новый (с шейдерами) или старый (с glBegin/glEnd)?

Comment: Нет, для этого нужно куда больше функций. И вообще, прежде чем задавать такой вопрос следует ознакомиться с каким-либо туториалом по теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать шейдерные программы Вершинный, Фрагментный. Загрузить их и текстуру на видяху, и будет вам счастье. Примерно так. Никаких циклов не надо все благодаря шейдерам.
За подробностями сюда: https://ravesli.com/urok-6-tekstury-v-opengl/
Примеры тут: https://github.com/Ravesli/OpenGL

P.S. в двух словах такие вещи не объяснить.